# Sequelize queryInterface does not set default value

Tags: javascript, orm, mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize v6 as orm in my js project. I am using the sequelize migrations. Inside one of those migrations i use the queryInterface to create a new column to a table.

I set the property defaultValue but inside my database (mariadb) the column gets created without any default value.

The code:

```js
 await queryInterface.addColumn('inventories', 'payload', {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '[]',
});
```

Comment: Currently i am using sequelize.query to use a raw sql query

Comment: Can you turn on SQL logging and look at the generated SQL?